# Handling device orientation for iOS 8 Portrait/Upside down

Tags: ios8, orientation, device-orientation, orientation-changes

My current code for Portrait/Upside down orientation only works for iOS 7 devices iPhone/iPad. However, for iOS 8 devices it doesn't work. The code I use is ...

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);

}
```

I'm working in Xcode 6.1, not using size classes and auto layout. Regular storyboard, no navigation controller.

I'm researching this and can't seem to find anything that works.
Is there a different way to do Portrait/Upside down orientation change for iOS 8 right now?